# Sass Invalid CSS: expected expression (e.g. 1px, bold), was "{"

Tags: css, sass

I have the following Sass, following [this example for @each](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#each-directive):

```
@each $flag in USA, EUR, JPN {
  a.#{$flag} {
    display:inline-block;
    overflow:hidden;
    width:0;
    height:11px;
    padding-left:16px; 
    background:url('http://res.cloudinary.com/mrengy/image/upload/v1470163121/#{$flag}.gif');
  }
}
```

It's just an example for an answer to another question. In CodePen, it is giving me an error:

> Invalid CSS after "USA, EUR, JPN ": expected expression (e.g. 1px, bold), was "{"

[Here's the example on CodePen](https://codepen.io/mrengy/pen/GqXqgV?editors=1100).

That error makes no sense. What is the problem here?

Comment: I know very little SASS, but I know SCSS. If you change the compiler to SCSS, your code works. Maybe if you haven't been working on this long, that's a switch you can still do...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your code is actually SCSS, not SASS.

To make it work as SASS, you need to get rid of curly braces, semi-colons and add some spaces.

Here's the corrected code:

```
@each $flag in USA, EUR, JPN 

  a.#{$flag} 
    display:inline-block
    overflow:hidden
    width: 0
    height: 11px
    padding-left: 16px
    background: url('http://res.cloudinary.com/mrengy/image/upload/v1470163121/#{$flag}.gif') no-repeat
```

https://codepen.io/vic3685/pen/akaEyo?editors=1100

Comment: Well, that's odd. I actually just changed the preprocessor in Codepen to use SCSS, and that resolved it as well.